# v-model did not update inside a for-in loop with dynamic object iterations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using an object `items` to show a list of inputs with `v-for`.

`items` is updated when the component `mounted`, but it only shows **two** inputs at first.

The third input will display after clicking the button or typing in the input. But the `items` value **doesn't update when the third input changes**.

I was wondering

1. Why the third item did not show at first. (I guess Vue doesn't keep track of the object changes for updating the view?)
2. Why clicking the button worked
3. Why the value in the third item did not update.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        show: true,
        items: {
          peter: {
            name: 'Peter',
            value: ''
          },
          kitty: {
            name: 'Kitty',
            value: ''
          }
        },
      }
    },
    watch: {
      show(newVal) {
        console.log('Alert is now ' + (newVal ? 'visible' : 'hidden'))
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.items.test = {
        name: 'Test',
        value: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggle() {
        console.log('Toggle button clicked')
        this.show = !this.show
      },
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="toggle">
      {{ show ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Alert
    </button>
    <div v-if="show">
      Hello!
    </div>
    <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
      <label>{{item.name}}:</label>
      <input type="text" name="item.name" v-model="items[index].value" />

    </div>
    <div>{{items}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue documentation describe this case

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, propertyName, value) method:
>
> You can also use the vm.$set instance method, which is an alias to the global Vue.set:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        show: true,
        items: {
          peter: {
            name: 'Peter',
            value: ''
          },
          kitty: {
            name: 'Kitty',
            value: ''
          }
        },
      }
    },
    watch: {
      show(newVal) {
        console.log('Alert is now ' + (newVal ? 'visible' : 'hidden'))
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$set(this.items, 'test', {
        name: 'Test',
        value: ''
      })
      /*
      this.items.test = {
        name: 'Test',
        value: ''
      }
      */
    },
    methods: {
      toggle() {
        console.log('Toggle button clicked')
        this.show = !this.show
      },
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="toggle">
      {{ show ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Alert
    </button>
    <div v-if="show">
      Hello!
    </div>
    <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
      <label>{{item.name}}:</label>
      <input type="text" name="item.name" v-model="items[index].value" />

    </div>
    <div>{{items}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Vue has a different way of tracking when it comes to update the UI*

Vue uses getters/setters on the data object for mutation tracking. When you execute `this.items = [{}, {}, {}, ...];`, It will go through the setter of table. In the setter, there's a function to notify the watcher and add this data changes to a queue.

Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array :

- When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
- When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

*Answer of your Question :* In consideration of above two statements, You have to update whole array including the unmodified rows.